# "Label at end of compound statement" error, MacPorts, CGMiner

Tags: c, macports

I'm trying to install cgminer on OS X using MacPorts. It's been nothing but trouble since the start, but with the proper tools, common sense, and the Internet I've been able to get this far. Essentially, the compilation jams on *sudo make install* indicating a jam at line 956 of util.c - here is the text of the terminal output:

```
   CC       cgminer-cgminer.o
   CC       cgminer-util.o
util.c: In function ‘nanosleep_abstime’:
util.c:956: error: label at end of compound statement
make[1]: *** [cgminer-util.o] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

And here is the contents of the cgminer copy of util.c opened in Xcode 4.6.3, cropped at nano sleep_abstime and with a comment inserted designating line 956:

```
static void nanosleep_abstime(struct timespec *ts_end)
{
     uint64_t now_ns, end_ns, diff_ns;
     struct timespec ts_diff;
     struct timeval now;

     end_ns = timespec_to_ns(ts_end);
     gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
     now_ns = timeval_to_ns(&now);
     if (unlikely(now_ns >= end_ns))
        goto out;
     diff_ns = end_ns - now_ns;
     ns_to_timespec(&ts_diff, diff_ns);
     nanosleep(&ts_diff, NULL);
out:
#ifdef WIN32
     timeEndPeriod(1);
#endif
} // LINE 956
#endif
```

Now, I'm not in any way, shape or form familiar with Unix/Linux commands or terminal in the least - I feel like a fish out of water, so everything I've learned I've had to learn by doing it wrong and then learning the hard way. However, I've read online that this error was solved by ending a label that was unresolved at the last portion of a function - that is, if the function ended at default:, a break; was placed between it and the end brace to resolve the error.

However, I have tried placing the break after the WIN32 #endif, inside the #ifdef preprocessor argument, and preceding it, directly after out:. All continue to fail the compiler. Any solutions for this? I feel like the solution is staring me in the face.

Here is relevant config/version information of my setup:

```
OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Xcode 4.6.3 w/ Command Line Tools installed
MacPorts version 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this code has not been compiled on anything except Windows!  Outside Windows, the `#ifdef WIN32`...`#endif` evaporates and, as you've seen, the label `out:` is left without a statement to label.

This is probably most clearly fixed by adding a null statement, explicitly for the non-Windows case:

```
out:
#ifdef WIN32
    timeEndPeriod(1);
#else
    ;
#endif
}
```

*(The two lines `#else` and `;` have been added.)*

Comment: Should've seen that one coming...been working on 3 comps lately, one Mac, one Ubuntu, and one Windows, so the error didn't hit like it usually would, silly me.